# Should we put [scope] down our scope?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Currently, the main-site [scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) tag is used to tag questions seeking specific advice about code scope. However, as this is a language-agnostic feature, it should be assumed to be a potential part of a review and thus unnecessary.

Should we put [scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) down our burnination scope?

Comment: not to be confused with [meta-tag:scope]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Code Review tags are more useful when they refer to:

1. The features that the code on question is implementing i.e [linked-list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list)
2. The context that question is originated from i.e [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge)
3. The subject that question is related to i.e [mathematics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics)
4. A generic programming functionality that usually takes part on most applications i.e [authorization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorization)
5. A generic programming concern i.e [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) or [design-patterns](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns)

And of course the language tag. So according to those usefulness rules [scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) shouldn't exist. And like you said should already be taken into account by the one doing the review.

Comment: I disagree with 2 by the way. Just slap [tag:programming-challenge] them, include a link to the original, include the text of the challenge and one should be fine. No point in having a tag for every origin. If you look closely you'll see [tag:project-euler] actually refers to [tag:programming-challenge] now.

Comment: @Mast Yeah I certainly agree (with the example provided). It's my 1st take on meta so blame me all you want.

Comment: 17 questions in 3+ years. Very few were well received. It's a meta tag. Kill it with fire.